# Linking errors with message_filters in Hydro

Tags: catkin, ros-hydro, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am migrating a node from Fuerte to Hydro that uses the message_filters ApproximateTime sync policy. The code being used for this is functionally identical to the example on the [message_filters wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Policy-Based_Synchronizer_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D), and worked great in Fuerte. But now when I try to build, I get the following linker errors:

```
CMakeFiles/vo_rgbd_node.dir/src/ros_server.cpp.o: In function `message_filters::Synchronizer >, sensor_msgs::Image_ >, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_ >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType> >::disconnectAll()':
ros_server.cpp:(.text._ZN15message_filters12SynchronizerINS_13sync_policies15ApproximateTimeIN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEES6_NS3_11CameraInfo_IS5_EENS_8NullTypeES9_S9_S9_S9_S9_EEE13disconnectAllEv[message_filters::Synchronizer >, sensor_msgs::Image_ >, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_ >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType> >::disconnectAll()]+0x41): undefined reference to `message_filters::Connection::disconnect()'
CMakeFiles/vo_rgbd_node.dir/src/ros_server.cpp.o: In function `message_filters::Connection message_filters::SimpleFilter > >::registerCallback > const> const&>(boost::function > const> const&)> const&)':
ros_server.cpp:(.text._ZN15message_filters12SimpleFilterIN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEE16registerCallbackIRKN3ros12MessageEventIKS4_EEEENS_10ConnectionERKN5boost8functionIFvT_EEE[message_filters::Connection message_filters::SimpleFilter > >::registerCallback > const> const&>(boost::function > const> const&)> const&)]+0x9a): undefined reference to `message_filters::Connection::Connection(boost::function const&)'
CMakeFiles/vo_rgbd_node.dir/src/ros_server.cpp.o: In function `message_filters::Connection message_filters::SimpleFilter > >::registerCallback > const> const&>(boost::function > const> const&)> const&)':
ros_server.cpp:(.text._ZN15message_filters12SimpleFilterIN11sensor_msgs11CameraInfo_ISaIvEEEE16registerCallbackIRKN3ros12MessageEventIKS4_EEEENS_10ConnectionERKN5boost8functionIFvT_EEE[message_filters::Connection message_filters::SimpleFilter > >::registerCallback > const> const&>(boost::function > const> const&)> const&)]+0x9a): undefined reference to `message_filters::Connection::Connection(boost::function const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The contents of my CMakeLists.txt are as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(vo_rgbd)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  geometry_msgs
  relative_nav_msgs
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

catkin_package()

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Eigne_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(vo_rgbd_node src/vo_rgbd_node.cpp src/ros_server.cpp src/pose_estimator.cpp)
add_dependencies(vo_rgbd_node relative_nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp)
target_link_libraries(vo_rgbd_node
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${Eigen_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Am I possibly missing something in my CMakeLists.txt that could be causing these errors, or might there be a different cause?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107531/linking-errors-with-message_filters-in-hydro/) by [dpkoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/7781/dpkoch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 132 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your CMakeLists.txt's`find_package`, you left off message_filters.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dpkoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/7781/dpkoch/) on 2013-12-05**:
Ah, I had thought that message_filters was part of roscpp, but I now see that those are both separate packages within the ros_comm stack. Adding message_filters to the `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)` and as a dependency in package.xml fixed the problem. Thanks!

**Comment by [smishra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4473/smishra/) on 2013-12-10**:
Also, you misspelled Eigen in the include directories